# With a SQL Server 2005 database that is set up as a Merge Replication Push Subscriber, is it possible to use the same database as Publisher as well?

Tags: sql-server, replication

We have Merge (Push) replication set up between the databases in our different offices.  Each database carries the complete set of data, so that the users in each office only need to connect to the database server in their office.  When users want to go off-site they need to pull a subset of data to a local (on user's laptop) SQL Express database.  Is it possible to use SQL Server 2005 replication to pull this subset from one of the Subscriber databases and then later replicate their local changes back?

**Edit**: We do not want the users in regional offices to replicate against our main publisher database, but against the Subscriber databases.  Each Subscriber must therefore act as a Publisher for the users in that office (maybe even using transactional replication in stead of merge replication)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but make the offsite users' SQL Server 2005 Express Edition a merge replication subscriber (i.e. pointing at your Distributor).

[Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151819(SQL.90).aspx).

Comment: Although it doesn't really cater for our specific scenario where each user (subscriber) needs his / her data to be filtered based on his User ID in the database, it is still the correct answer to the original question :)